# Google Compute Engine instances cannot ping each other on internal addresses

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a few instances running in Google Compute engine:

```
NAME       ZONE       MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP      STATUS
inst-dns2  xx-xxxx-x  f1-micro                    10.240.0.4   x.x.x.x          RUNNING
inst-st0   xx-xxxx-x  f1-micro                    10.240.0.2   x.x.x.x          RUNNING
inst-www0  xx-xxxx-x  n1-standard-2               10.240.0.3   x.x.x.x          RUNNING
inst-dns3  xx-xxxx-x  f1-micro                    10.240.0.5   x.x.x.x          RUNNING
```

As you can see, they all have IPs in the same subnet.  I have been using the built-in `default` network since I started.

```
NAME     MODE    IPV4_RANGE     GATEWAY_IPV4
default  legacy  10.240.0.0/16  10.240.0.1
```

I still have the `default-allow-internal` firewall rule:

```
NAME                    NETWORK  SRC_RANGES     RULES                         SRC_TAGS  TARGET_TAGS
default-allow-internal  default  10.240.0.0/16  tcp:1-65535,udp:1-65535,icmp
```

Yet, none of my instances can ping one another.

[The docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/subnetworks#subnetworks_and_firewall_rules) state, "In the default network, by default, all virtual machine instances within a network can communicate with each other, because of the default firewall rules described above."

So, I am consfused.  I thought I could do this without having to create custom networks and all that.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: What if you stop and restart these instances?

Comment: That did not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using official FreeBSD instance images instead of my own pre-built ones.  Beware: the official images have their own issues, such as problems  system date/time.  Do your research and test before going into production.